# PDFBox - How to access whole form

Tags: java, pdfbox

**EDITED**
I'm using some code to extract fields and data of a signed PDF. It's a signed PDF with several forms with some fields and their values.

[image]

But I'm only getting the signature field/value with the current code:

```
/**
 * This will print all the fields from the document.
 * 
 * @param pdfDocument The PDF to get the fields from.
 * 
 * @throws IOException If there is an error getting the fields.
 */
public void printFields(PDDocument pdfDocument) throws IOException
{
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> fields = acroForm.getFields();

    System.out.println(fields.size() + " top-level fields were found on the form");

    for (PDField field : fields)
    {
        processField(field, "|--", field.getPartialName());
    }
}

private void processField(PDField field, String sLevel, String sParent) throws IOException
{
    String partialName = field.getPartialName();

    if (field instanceof PDNonTerminalField)
    {
        if (!sParent.equals(field.getPartialName()))
        {
            if (partialName != null)
            {
                sParent = sParent + "." + partialName;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sLevel + sParent);

        for (PDField child : ((PDNonTerminalField)field).getChildren())
        {
            processField(child, "|  " + sLevel, sParent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        String fieldValue = field.getValueAsString();
        StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder(sLevel);
        outputString.append(sParent);
        if (partialName != null)
        {
            outputString.append(".").append(partialName);
        }
        outputString.append(" = ").append(fieldValue);
        outputString.append(",  type=").append(field.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println(outputString);
    }
}
```

But getting

```
1 top-level fields were found on the form
|--ENVELOPEID_EE81E3AFDC0143968B9D253C5DEA7A2B.ENVELOPEID_EE81E3AFDC0143968B9D253C5DEA7A2B = org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.PDSignature@1c53fd30,  type=org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDSignatureField
```

How can I get the contents of the PDF?

Regards

Comment: Maybe xfa... can you share the PDF?

Comment: An *image* of the PDF does not suffice, we need the actual PDF.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzi02J2A226WMk5XU3FlSWxlM3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is a PDF with a "flattened" form. It just looks like a form but it no longer is. It is just a bunch of lines and glyphs that looks like fields. To extract data you'd have to use text extraction, text extraction by area (if you have a lot of such PDFs) or image processing.

Comment: but I'm not able to extract the data, just the label of the "fileds". How can I get it?